# Die question probability

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

We are rolling a fair die and let say $S(k)$  is sum of the $k$ rolls.
and $P(n)$ is the probability  that the sequence $(S(1),S(2),...)$ includes $n$. Find the limit of $P(n)$

How I approached the problem:
We can reach $n$ from $n-1,n-2,n-3,n-4,n-5,n-6$ with prob. $1/6$
and these probabilities are independent from $P(n)$
Hence there is a recursion 
$$P(n)=\frac{1}{6}\left(P(n-1)+P(n-2)+P(n-3)+P(n-4)+P(n-5)+P(n-6)\right)  $$

but I could not solve the recursion
generating functions did not work.
In addition,this is a markov chain question,can anybody explain the relation between the question and markov chain.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Intuitively, for large $n$ we must have that $P(n)$ is independent of $n$.  As each roll adds on average $\frac 72$, we must have $P(n) \to \frac 27$  The problem with your recursion is that you can reach $n$ from $n-6$ in more ways than just rolling a $6$

Comment: I believe this recursion is correct.  In order to reach the sum of $n$, one of six mutually exclusive events must occur: a sum of $n-1$ is reached followed by a roll of 1, a sum of $n-2$ is reached followed by a roll of 2, etc.  $P(j)$ is the probability that the sum $j$ is ever reached, so this recursion yields the probability that the sum will ever be $n$, when $n>6$.  I have a proof using Markov chains that the limit is 2/7 starting on page 40 of this pdf: http://www.madandmoonly.com/doctormatt/mathematics/dice1.pdf